# Best practice when returning boolean values in PHP

Tags: php

I noticed lately that eclipse is suggesting me the use of constants TRUE and FALSE from core.php when returning true or false from a function.

In other words should I use

```
function misc () 
{
    ...

    return true;
}
```

or

```
function misc () 
{
    ...

    return TRUE;
}
```

I know they are the same thing because of the way these constants are defined in core.php

```
define ('TRUE', true);
define ('FALSE', false);
```

So if anyone could explain what's best practice I would really appreciate.

Comment: at the point where you care about whether `true` or `TRUE` is better, you have definitely problems with your priorities. also, defining TRUE is kind of completely pointless, since true exists. do you have any idea, *why* those constants were defined?

Comment: Don't define keywords for once. True and false exist in any language and there's really, really no need to redefine them. As for `true` or `TRUE` pick on and stick with it.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I really am puzzled too about why the TRUE and FALSE constants were defined in core.php. Maybe someone has a good anwser

Comment: you should go asking. besides, using TRUE and FALSE instead of true and false could result into unforeseen troubles if someone decides to mess with your code - just imagine a `define('TRUE', false)`-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is, if you do not have your own coding standard, to follow the [FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/) coding standards.

According to FIG PSR-2, [there is no ambiguity what so ever about this particular issue](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#2-5-keywords-and-true-false-null):

> The PHP constants true, false, and null MUST be in lower case.

Comment: this is what I was looking for